# Using sed to match a dynamic, multi-line string and append to it

Tags: sed, ansible, yaml

I have an Ansible yaml file that I want to append on a new line after `state: present` in the example matches below with `use: package_manager` using `sed`.

```yaml
# Example 1
- name: Package X Install
  package:
    name:
      - package_1
      - package_2
    state: present

# Example 2
- name: Package Y Install
  package:
    name: package_3
    state: present

# Example 3
- block:
  - name: Package Z Install
    package:
      name: package_4
      state: present

# etc. Further examples would be any combination, iteration of the above.
```

However, there are multiple entries throughout the playbook that have a variable amount of preceding whitespace. The match needs to be directly under the `state` entry and have the same amount of indentation. I had trouble using `state` as a search anchor for `sed` as the Ansible playbook has other modules that use `state: present`.

The furthest I got was:

```bsh
$ sed '/\s\{4,\}package:*\s\{6,\}state: present/a \s\{6,\}use: package_manager'
```

As you can tell, it doesn't work at all. I'm lost; any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Unless you are in a very specific situation, `package` should detect the package manager to use by itself. The `use` option is more for debug/tests purpose than for production use. It would be better to fix the problem preventing the auto detection from gathered facts rather than patching your tasks at wild. In other words, double check you're not in an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can capture the spaces from the matched line and then substitute while inserting

```
sed 's/^\( *\)state: present$/&\n\1use: package_manager/' ansible.yaml
```

Output:

```
# Example 1
- name: Package X Install
  package:
    name:
      - package_1
      - package_2
    state: present
    use: package_manager

# Example 2
- name: Package Y Install
  package:
    name: package_3
    state: present
    use: package_manager

# Example 3
- block:
  - name: Package Z Install
    package:
      name: package_4
      state: present
      use: package_manager

# etc. Further examples would be any combination, iteration of the above.
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I can't use `state: present` as the search anchor because other modules outside of `package` use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper YAML parser on the data in the question,

```
$ yq -y '(.. | .package? | select(.state == "present")) |= (.use = "package_manager")' file.yml
- name: Package X Install
  package:
    name:
      - package_1
      - package_2
    state: present
    use: package_manager
- name: Package Y Install
  package:
    name: package_3
    state: present
    use: package_manager
- block:
    - name: Package Z Install
      package:
        name: package_4
        state: present
        use: package_manager
```

This uses [the `yq` parser](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to add the `use: package_manager` key+value in each `package` section that contains a `state` key corresponding to the value `present`.

It does this by recursing over all the data, picking out the `package` sections that have a `state` key with the value `present`.  It then adds the new key and value to those sections.